# Multiple checkbox value pass on button click

Tags: angular5

I am working on the edit product page. When user clicks on edit button, a modal is open which consist of list of data and checkbox containing following data as well.

```
0: {id: "01", name: "abc"}
1: {id: "02", name: "Factory"}
2: {id: "03", name: "Restaurants"}
3: {id: "04", name: "Cater"}
```

Lets say user selects a row with following data:

```
{
    id: 1
    code: "21184683"
    name: "YL IB"
    channel_ids: (5) ["07", "12", "03", "14", "05"]
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="TargetForm" *ngIf="TargetForm"
        (ngSubmit)="submitUpdatedRecord(TargetForm.value)">
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <li *ngFor="let item of this.data">
        <label>
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                formControlName="channel_ids"
                name="channel_ids"
                [checked]="editProductData.channel_ids.indexOf(item.id) > -1" />
                {{item.name}}
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="submit">update</button>
```

Now I am not being able to pass the selected checkbox id on update button click.

Answer (score 0):

```
(change)=someFunction(id);
```

Attach it to checkbox input. Use function that will trigger on checkbox change and pass the id however You like in the component.